# How to pass URL into <img> tag from Webapi to accept image of base64?

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, base64

How to pass URL from `Webapi` into `<img>` tag. I have converted the image into `base64 string` and inserted into `Database` as a `varbinary`.

```
<img src="https://localhost:44381/api/Account/get-resource-image;data:image/jpg;base64" alt="img"/>
```

Comment: Please add some code for the issue. This looks unclear...

Comment: <img src="https://localhost:44381/api/Account/get-resource-image;data:image/jpg;base64" alt="img"/>

Comment: this is the code which in I passed Url

Comment: Also give code for your webapi function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `data:image/png;base64` at the start of Webapi endpoint in `<img>` src and not after. See the below code.

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,https://localhost:44381/api/Account/get-resource-imagedata" alt="img"/>
```

**Another way to achieve same thing:**

**JQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:44381/api/Account/get-resource-imagedata',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#imgImage').attr('src', data);
        }
});
```

**In HTML:**

`<img id="imgImage" src="#" alt="img"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use angularjs `ng-src`. First execute a GET request in your controller and then save the response in a variable to use it with `ng-src`:

```
$http.get('https://localhost:44381/api/Account/get-resource-imagedata').then(function(response) {
    $scope.image = response.data;
});
```

In template:

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{image}}" alt="img"/>
```